# Check continuity of integers and return uniques

Tags: python, list, pandas

Suppose i have a list like this:

```
[1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0]
```

I want to check the continuity of the 1's and -1's.

Expected output:

```
[(1.0, 1.0), (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0), (1.0), (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0),....,(1.0), (0,0), (1.0, 1.0),( -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0)]

[1,-1,1,-1,....,1,0,1,-1]
```

for consecutive positive and negative values, it will return only ones.

It's a little bit confusing for me. Can anybody help or suggest me the correct way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `[tuple(g) for _, g in itertools.groupby(l)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A high level solution would involve *grouping* adjacent elements. There are more than one ways to do this. I've outlined one with pure python using `itertools`, and another with pandas since that's what you've tagged the question with.

**Python**
`itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

r = [tuple(g) for _, g in groupby(lst)]
r
[(1.0, 1.0), (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0), (1.0,), (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0), (1.0,), (-1.0, -1.0), (1.0,), (-1.0, -1.0), (1.0,), (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (-1.0, -1.0), (1.0,), (-1.0,), (1.0,), (-1.0,), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (-1.0, -1.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0), (1.0,), (-1.0,), (1.0,), (-1.0,), (1.0,), (-1.0,), (0.0,), (1.0, 1.0), (-1.0,), (1.0,), (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0)]
```

If you want unique values from `groupby`, make a slight change to `groupby` call -

```
r = [i for i, _ in groupby(lst)]
```

---

**Pandas**
`groupby` + `shift` + `cumsum` + `apply`

```
x = pd.Series(lst)
r = x.groupby(x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum()).apply(tuple)    
r

1                               (1.0, 1.0)
2           (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
3                                   (1.0,)
4           (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
5                                   (1.0,)
6                             (-1.0, -1.0)
7                                   (1.0,)
8                             (-1.0, -1.0)
9                                   (1.0,)
10                      (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
11                         (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
12                            (-1.0, -1.0)
13                                  (1.0,)
14                                 (-1.0,)
15                                  (1.0,)
16                                 (-1.0,)
17                    (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
18                            (-1.0, -1.0)
19               (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
20                (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
21                                  (1.0,)
22                                 (-1.0,)
23                                  (1.0,)
24                                 (-1.0,)
25                                  (1.0,)
26                                 (-1.0,)
27                                  (0.0,)
28                              (1.0, 1.0)
29                                 (-1.0,)
30                                  (1.0,)
31    (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0)
dtype: object
```

To find unique values, you can use `mean` or `unique`.  -

```
r = x.groupby(x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum()).mean()
```

I've used `mean`, but they do the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

use `groupby` from `itertools` here

```
>>> x = [1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0]

>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> print([tuple(j) for i, j in groupby(x)])

[(1.0, 1.0), (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0), (1.0,), (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0), (1.0,), (-1.0, -1.0), (1.0,), (-1.0, -1.0), (1.0,), (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (-1.0, -1.0), (1.0,), (-1.0,), (1.0,), (-1.0,), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (-1.0, -1.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0), (1.0,), (-1.0,), (1.0,), (-1.0,), (1.0,), (-1.0,), (0.0,), (1.0, 1.0), (-1.0,), (1.0,), (-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0)]
```

Comment: Just saying that this is tagged pandas. Also, the `groupby` solution was mine first :)

Comment: while I was busy compiling my expression, you posted the comment. I am really sorry if I hurt your sentimental, Please suggest what should I do next ?

Comment: @akash, if i want to take the average or the unique values from each tuple. How can i do that?

Comment: I am baffled by the constant slew of hostility I encounter on this website. I have nothing against users posting the same answers as mine, as long as it is not plagiarised.

Comment: @Dheeraj See my answer with pandas, it really is simple.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, sure

Comment: @akashkarothiya: I'm sorry if I hurt your sentiments by saying your answer is the same as mine :)